# How can I implement auto suggest/complete box using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, autosuggest

Requirement:-

User input - Suppose i have table called Customer_Data and it has columns called `customer_id` and `customer_name`.

User will start typing table name then it should suggest related table names and after that if user is willing to select an column it should suggest column names based table name.

Ex.

```
1. Customer_Data.customer_name
2. Customer_Data.customer_id
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @jaboja how to populate suggestions after . ?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and code sample there (note that JQueryUI requires you to include some additional JS and CSS in your `<head>`). Example:

```
$("#yourInput").autocomplete({
  source: Object.values(Customer_Data)
  // assuming Customer_Data is an object existing in your code
});
```

Btw. if you need to update the list after initialization you can call the `.autocomplete({source: ...});` again to update it.

How you construct the *Customer_Data* object is up to you.